# Prevent overlap on multiple rows of `Position: sticky;` headers (without calculating/hardcoding heights)

Tags: css

I want to have multiple rows of headers (say, `h1` through `h6`), where each sub-header sticks directly below the header above it (Each `h6` sticks to the bottom of the currently stickied `h5`, which sticks to the bottom of the currently stickied `h4`, etc).

When using `position: sticky; top: 0;` on all the sticky headers, they will overlap at the top of the page. The overlap is not desired:

```
h1, h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
h1, h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div>div {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>a header</h1>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>a1 header</h2>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>a2 header</h2>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>a3 header</h2>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>b header</h1>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>b1 header</h2>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>b2 header</h2>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>b3 header</h2>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>c header</h1>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>c1 header</h2>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>c2 header</h2>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>c3 header</h2>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the `h2` header is changed to `top: 30px`, the overlap is removed, but this only works if all the `h1` heights are known to be exactly `30px`. This looks better, but the hardcoded value `30px` is not desired:

```
h1, h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
h2 {
  top: 30px;
}
```

```css
h1, h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
h2 {
  top: 30px;
}
div>div {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>a header</h1>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>a1 header</h2>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>a2 header</h2>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>a3 header</h2>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>b header</h1>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>b1 header</h2>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>b2 header</h2>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>b3 header</h2>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>c header</h1>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>c1 header</h2>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>c2 header</h2>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>c3 header</h2>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to prevent this overlap without knowing the height of the `h1`? Does `position: sticky` provide any means of doing this (without resorting to javascript to calculate the `h1` height)?

Comment: Did you ever obtain a pure CSS answer to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cooked up a little JQuery code to help with your issue of hardcoding the heights. Instead of hardcoding and adjusting it again and again, you could make use of the .height() function to find the height and apply it using javascript itself like shown in the code snippet below.

Hope, it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h2 = $('h2').height();
  var h3 = $('h3').height() + h2;
  var h4 = $('h4').height() + h3;
  var h5 = $('h5').height() + h4;
  var h6 = $('h6').height() + h5;
  $("h2").css("top", h2);
  $("h3").css("top", h3);
  $("h4").css("top", h4);
  $("h5").css("top", h5);
  $("h6").css("top", h6);
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

div>div {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>a header</h1>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <p>a content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>a1 header</h2>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <p>a1 content</p>
    <div>
      <h3>a3 header</h3>
      <p>a3 content</p>
      <p>a3 content</p>
      <p>a3 content</p>
      <div>
        <h4>a4 header</h4>
        <p>a4 content</p>
        <p>a4 content</p>
        <p>a4 content</p>
        <div>
          <h5>a5 header</h5>
          <p>a5 content</p>
          <p>a5 content</p>
          <p>a5 content</p>
          <div>
            <h6>a6 header</h6>
            <p>a6 content</p>
            <p>a6 content</p>
            <p>a6 content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>a2 header</h2>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
    <p>a2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>a3 header</h2>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
    <p>a3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>b header</h1>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <p>b content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>b1 header</h2>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
    <p>b1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>b2 header</h2>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
    <p>b2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>b3 header</h2>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
    <p>b3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>c header</h1>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <p>c content</p>
  <div>
    <h2>c1 header</h2>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
    <p>c1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>c2 header</h2>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
    <p>c2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>c3 header</h2>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
    <p>c3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking for a javascript-less solution, but it's good to know that it is still reasonable to do with javascript. Thanks.

Comment: I did try it without javascript, but there's no alternative without hardcoding the values in CSS, since we're making use of sticky which switches from relative to absolute when reaches the top. JS, is the only easier alternative, if you want to avoid absolute values in CSS.

Comment: @uber5001 Seeing, as no one else has answered or attempted to answer your query, and if you found this helpful be sure to mark it. Cheers

Comment: I've been thinking about it for a while, and I think it's impossible in pure css, since this requires `position: sticky` to create a new block formatting context in order to position elements with the usual height/margin/padding spacing. It might be worth mentioning in your answer that (with only css) it is not possible.